# 10.2 install ExampleData["Geometry3D"] properties contain only Name and Polygon count

Tags: graphics3d

I just installed 10.2 and tried to load some example 3D geometry to work with the new features. The documentation continues to use the same examples, but they don't work in my 10.2.0 Win7-64bit install. They work fine on 10.0.2.0. I can't imagine this is a generalized problem, and seems like an install problem, but any suggestions (or can anyone confirm or deny this as an issue)?

The following only returns {Name, PolygonCount} for each of the 27 examples.

```
ExampleData[#, "Properties"] & /@ ExampleData["Geometry3D"]
```

Display just returns the command (not the model).

```
ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}]
```

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, that's 10.2 Linux for you, correct?

Comment: Works also for me, v10.2, OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: It works with 10.2 on both Linux and Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Assuming no network connection problems, perhaps try first `RebuildPacletData[]` and if that does not help, delete the entire `Paclets` folder in your `$UserBaseDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks ilian. Rebuild didn't work, but the deletion of the Paclets folder did it. It must have been corrupted from transition from 10.0.2 to 10.2, as I opted to keep the old version instead of deleting it. (I also was not aware it was paclet data vs. part of the install).